# How many time Asynchronous methods running per minute

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services

I'm working on an Asynchronous method in now a days getting started from this link

- [Calling Synchronous Methods Asynchronously](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e08f6yc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Now, what should I do if I want to see that how many times my method run in 1 minute?

For example, 25000 transactions in 20 mins. etc.....

Thanks

Comment: this is unanswerable; it would depend on: machine specification, size / duration of the method, how many cores, how many concurrent parallel operations you did at once, whether the method is IO-bound, CPU-bound, or time-bound, synchronization strategy, other load on the machine, etc

Comment: For info, a trivial test shows I can get 32288 `BeginInvoke` per-second per-virtual-core on a hypervised, hyperthreaded i7. But in reality, it is better to perform fewer async operations, each of which does more work - less overheads.

Comment: @Marc Gravell I am asking about how do we find that how many times methods runs per minutes want to check the performance in another words, If we define a static variable or anything else which tell us how many time a Asynchronous method execute per minutes. I think it is answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most simplistic way to achieve this is to have a counter that the asynchronous method updates each time it runs (be aware of locking etc). Then all you need to do is record your start time and compare the two whenever you want...

Start time = 11:56
Start running async task(s)...
Check at 11:57 and counter = 23 means it has run 23 times in one minute

You can check after one minute, one hour or whenever you want. There are other ways of course but this would be the most simplistic!